# How does this for loop output a decending number of "#" (top being most amount while bottom being least)?

Tags: java, for-loop, iteration

I'm attempting to solve some Java questions and I came across a question that asked me to print out a diamond of size `n`.

Since I got stumped on this question, I decided to look up other's solutions to get an idea as to how I could tackle this problem.

A diamond of size 2 should look like this by the way.

```
##*##
#***#
##*##
```

However, one part of the code really stumped me out and that is how does the `#` get printed out in that manner.

Here is what I found for the top left bit of the diamond, basically this bit:

```
##
#
```

Here is the code for that:

```
 public static void printDiamond(int k){
        for(int i=1; i <= k; i++) {
            for(int j = i; j <= k; j++) {
                System.out.print("#");
            }
            System.out.println("");
         }
 }
```

and the output when k = 5:

```
#####
####
###
##
#
```

From my understanding, int `j` is looping upwards since it's declared as `i` which also loops upwards until it reaches `k`.

Shouldn't that print out 1,2,3,4,5 diamonds instead since the loop goes from 0 to k, which is 5?

I was expecting the output to be like:

```
#
##
###
####
#####
```

Can someone explain how does the code snippet I attached returns the output from top to bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple pen and paper exercise will uncover the details.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
    for(int j = i; j <= k; j++) {
    ...
   }
}
```

When `i = 1`, `j` runs from `1` to `k`. So, it will print the star `k` times. That is how you get `k` stars in row 1.

When `i = 2`, `j` runs from `2` to `k`. So, it will print the star `k - 1` times. That is how you get `k - 1` stars in row 2.

And so on...

When `i = k`, `j` runs from `k` to `k` which is one time and hence you get only one star in the last row.

Answer (score 0):

Initial value of `j` is set to incrementing `i` and the inner loop is limited with the fixed value `k`.  That is, the first run prints `#` from 1 to 5 (5 times), the second run prints from 2 to 5, etc. and the number of prints is *decreasing*.

To print the lower part in *increasing* way, the limit should be set to `i`: `for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++0) System.out.print("#")`.

Also, the inner loops may be replaced with the method `String::repeat` available since Java 11:

```java
public static void diamond(int k) {
    // upper part, decreasing # increasing *
    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
        System.out.println("#".repeat(k - i) + "*".repeat(2 * i - 1) + "#".repeat(k - i));
    }
    
    // lower part, decreasing * increasing #
    for (int i = 1; i < k; i++) {
        System.out.println("#".repeat(i) + "*".repeat(2 * (k - i) - 1) + "#".repeat(i));
    }
}
```